# Conditionally show form elements based on drop downlist selection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Pardon my inexperience, I've got C# chops but I'm just starting to learn ASP.NET MVC framework.

So I've got some models that look like this:

```
public abstract class Movement
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public abstract MovementType Type { get; }
}

public class WeightedMovement : Movement
{
    public override MovementType Type
    {
        get
        {
            return MovementType.WeightBased;
        }           
    }

    public double Weight { get; set; }
}

public class LengthMovement : Movement
{
    public int Distance { get; set; }

    public override MovementType Type
    {
        get
        {
            return MovementType.LengthBased;
        }
    }
}

public enum MovementType
{
    LengthBased,
    WeightBased
}
```

In the Create view and I want to use a combo box to select the type and then have the appropriate form elements appear (right now that's just either a text box for the Weight or Distance).

Here's what the view looks like so far:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Type, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Type)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Type)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div> 
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I've only ever done web work for a hobby, never professionally so I my go to naive way to do this would be to use jQuery to remove or add elements to the DOM and then casting to the correct concrete type based upon the Type property in the Controller method.

That all seems to be working around the framework instead of working with it. Are there razor tags I don't know about? Am I approaching this wrong? This obviously isn't new but I couldn't think of the right search terms for it.

Comment: This requires some JavaScript. You need to hook to the `onchange` event (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) of the combo box and set the `display` properties of other elements

Comment: You don't have to add/remove elements from the DOM to make them visible/invisible. But still, you need a client side script for this, jQuery would do fine.

Comment: You can, in the JQuery event handling your onchange event, create an Ajax call to your controllers action/function, and make that action/function return a partial view, which you can render on your main form/View